# What should be the most optimized approach for solving this kind of problem? (Google Foobar Level 3)

Tags: python, java, performance, complexity-theory, hint

After a long break, I started continuing the **Google Foobar Challenge**. Right now, I am on the last problem of **Level 3**. Was wondering what should be right way to approach such array-related problem. *No direct solution please, just hints* :)
(I am trying to do it with Java rn but might give Python a chance if there can be performance gaps between the codes)[image]
Thank you.[image][image]

Comment: I guess you do a depth-first traversal of all the states until you reach a terminal state, and for each step in each path you multiply by the current chance of getting in there. And you add that chance to the total chance of each terminal state. The only problem is if you get into loops... Maybe there's some other smart graph traversal algorithm for that.

Comment: Yeah. Also, I think the most difficult part is.. getting to the same state back.